# How to delete rows of my googlesheets using R

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I am using the `googlesheets4` package to access my *Googlesheets*.
I can retrieve the data from my file named *Youtube* and the sheet named *Youtube_Links* but I would like to delete some rows, for example rows *16* to *18* for all columns.

I have seen recently a `sheets_delete()` function was added on [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/pull/137) but when I do `lsf.str("package:googlesheets4")`
to see all the functions of this package I don't see that function in the list.

Do you know the steps I need to take to be able to use it?

I tried the following but without any success: `sheets_delete(Youtube, sheet = "Youtube_Links", range = "16:18", shift = NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [downloaded the development version from GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4) and have the sheets_delete() function:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/googlesheets4")
```

Comment: Thx a lot, didn't see that one. I having trouble to install the package, here is the error I get: `E> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
E>   namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.3 is required`    but I checked and the version of my 'vctrs' is 0.2.4  so I don't understand the issue.

Comment: I actually have this issue with my Docker session, not locally. I don't know how to solve this problem though... still your answer is valid so I will mark it as such.

Comment: Now that you say that I think I had the same error. I didn’t check my current version of ‘vctrs’, but restarted the R sessions and installed ‘vctrs’ through the RStudio GUI and reran the install_github, but this probably doesn’t help with the Docker issue.

Comment: hi @bs93 just wondering if sheets_delete() function is still working for you? It is not for me anymore...